# initialising in constructor parameter vs new Keyword in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript

CODE 1 :

```
 import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {exampleClass} from './exampleClass'
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
       list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];

       constructor(a:exampleClass) {
        a.hello();
       }
    }
```

Code 2 :

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {exampleClass} from './exampleClass'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];

   constructor() {
     const a = new exampleClass ;

   }

}
```

exampleClass.ts Cose :

```
export class exampleClass {
    hello(){
        console.log("A");
    }
}
```

why code 1 gives error and code prints A In Console And Whats The Difference Between Two initialisation Method ?

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code,

```
export class AppComponent {
    list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
    constructor(a:exampleClass) {
      a.hello();
    }
 }
```

The `exampleClass` should be a `service` and `services` can be injected into the `constructor` as a `parameter`.

So, you might get the error  **No provider for HeroDetailComponent**

So, if `exampleClass` was a service it might have worked.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read about **Dependency Injection** in Angular: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-pattern (and maybe in general, too).

In the first case, `AppComponent` does not need to know anything about the details of `exampleClass`. In the second case, you are deciding what class exactly are you using.

In the first case, when `AppComponent` is instantiated, Angular will take care of the parameters for you, instantiating the needed class. The advantage os this approach is that you may not want to always use the same class there. Maybe in your tests you want to use another mocked class. In the second case, you can't do that: `AppComponent` is tightly coupled with `exampleClass`.

In the first case, you decide what kind of instance the component will receive, without affecting the component. In the second case, that is not true. If you wanted to pass not `exampleClass`, but a derived class, you should have to touch it. In fact, if those classes's constructors were not parameterless, `AppComponent` should have to know how to instantiate them, too.

And the reason you receive an error is, I assume, that you haven't decorated `exampleClass` with `@Injectable()`. This decorator tells Angular that this class might be instantiated via dependency injection.

Besides, you should add `exampleClass` to the `providers` section of your `AppModule`

```
@Injectable() export class exampleClass { ... }

@NgModule({
    providers: [exampleClass],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code 1 is when you want a service to be **shared between components**.

For storing data for example -> If you do this.service.data = 'test';
All others component with code 1 will be able to

```
console.log(this.service.data); // print 'test'
```

The code 2 you instantiate it so the service is **a new instance scoped into your component**.